# What is the best method to execute script on remote via Jenkins

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins

Am looking for the best & proper method to execute script on remote via Jenkins job.
What is better:

- Write the commands directly on the Jenkins "Exec command" label on the "Send files or execute commands over SSH" tab.
- Just copy a bash file to the remote and execute it through Jenkins "Exec Com.." label command.

The reason I'm asking this question is because I am struggling with the second approach (i.e. execute local file which located on the remote...) and thinking maybe that not the best practice.

In addition, should I execute the script using sudo (because running as sudo causes me gitlab issues when try to clone..).
And when I am execute the the script he ask for password.
So far added permissions to /etc/sudoers not do the job but I'm thinking maybe that's a tab/lines issue...possible ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would go for SSH protocol approach (Simple, secure and reliable). Moreover, there are some plugins already made for those use cases you've mentioned.

[1. SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+plugin)

> You can use the SSH Plugin to run shell commands on a remote machine
>   via ssh.

So this plugin would fit into your first option of executing script or commands on remote via SSH.

[2. Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)

> The goal of the Publish Over plugins is to provide a consistent set of
>   features and behaviors when sending build artifacts ... somewhere.

The Publish over SSH plugin will allow you copy files to a remote server and execute arbitrary commands on the remote server. So this fits into your second approach where you want to first copy script and then execute.

Really you can use any of those plugins (Both use SSH so it's more secure). The question is what suits you the most. Choose wisely :)